# Prevent Duplicate Google Indexing When Moving From www to non-www (Search Console)

Tags: google, google-search-console, domains, search-engine-indexing, subdomain

I want to move my website away from using the www subdomain. I am using Squarespace which will provide automatic 301 redirects for all pages on the www subdomain to the non-www. I have a sitemap submitted in Google Search Console.

When I make the switch, will Google's index understand that the site was moved from www to non-www? Will it display search results as non-www and send visitors to the correct non-www site? I don't want any duplicate indexing across www and non-www.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create two profiles in search consoles and select the preferred one. That’s how to tell Google Search Console... but you also need to ensure the following activities are performed as they are essential:
- Update canonical tags to not use www
- Update internal links to not use www
- Update XML sitemap/s to the new URLs

Also worth updating high value backlinks to your site if possible. Things like your Facebook and Twitter links are easy, but if you have any other profiles this just helps to preserve authority from being lost through redirects.

Comment: Has that answered your question?

Comment: Yes, this was useful. Thank you very much!